# i have 5 elements in a list , need to find average and perfom certain task if the average is below 40%

Tags: python

I have 5 elements in a list , that is basically the transfer rate of an interface,
list1=[20, 80, 270, 100, 30]
in kbps.
i want to do average of these 5 elements and and perform certain task if the average is below 40%.
also need a precise scaling mechanism so that the average can be scaled from 0% to 100%

typing random numbers for example
list1=[20, 80, 270, 100, 30]
average is 30%
the average is below the standard of 40%
print average is low

Comment: what have you tired

Comment: you might want to make your question a bit clearer, I have no idea what you describing "average" as.

Answer (score -1):

Finding the average of a list is easy.

```
>>> a = [30, 50, 80]
>>> sum(a) / len(a)
53.333333333333336
```

Comparing that to the number 40 and inserting that comparison into a conditional statement is likewise easy.

```
>>> sum(a) / len(a) > 40
True
>>> if sum(a) / len(a) > 40: print("above 40")
... else: print("at or below 40")
...
above 40
```